# MongoDB "Unescaped colon in authority section" error

Tags: node.js

I was trying to connect mongodb and all. it was going well until i got an "Unescaped colon in authority section" error. anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: We don't see an error nor do we see any code that could cause the error. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Sorry im new to this stackover flow or really getting help from the internet thing.

Comment: I did fix it though. with the help of a dev discord server I joined.